# Unable to navigate to Folders in Home Directory

Tags: command-line, directory

```
whyshock@VaishakJ:/home$ cd Downloads   
bash: cd: Downloads: No such file or directory    
whyshock@VaishakJ:/home$ cd /whyshock    
bash: cd: /whyshock: No such file or directory    
whyshock@VaishakJ:/home$
```

[image: Screenshot Attached]

Comment: And who told you to put a / in front of whyshock in the last command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/home` is  not your home directory. `/home/whyshock` is.

Do one of the following to get to your home directory:

```
cd /home/whyshock
cd ~
cd "$HOME"
cd
```

To navigate to a directory in your home directory, you can do either of:

```
cd ~/Downloads
cd "$HOME"/Downloads
```

Comment: Thanks!! That reply was really fast. I'm just getting started using the terminal! Would like you to help me more with this. :)

Comment: get 20 rep @VaishakJ and you can enter chat. Often someone there will help a new person get started.  Putting all newbie questions on AU will take longer and also flood the frontpage ;-)

Comment: Will Do! :) . The Struggle is Real though :P

Answer (score 2):

Not only you are not on your user home directory `/home/whyshock`, as [muru points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/750355/169736), but when you try to navigate to it you are prefixing a slash to the directory name. `cd /whyshock` will try to navigate to a directory named "whyshock" in your root directory or `/`, which simply doesn't exist.

Whenever you start up your shell, by default is on the home directory already, without you having to move to the `/home/whyshock` directory. There's a nice section on the [FSH specifications](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s08.html) about this directory.